# Cant't get another viewController's property 'view' in the viewController

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

```
self.one=[[SSone alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:self.one];
[self.view addSubview:self.one.view];
```

When the program execute the **[self.view addSubview:self.one.view]**, something is wrong .when i enter 'po self.one.view', the result is

```
(lldb) po self.one.view error: Execution was interrupted, reason: 
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff57e94ff8).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `[self.view addSubview:self.one.view];` you have to call this:

```
[self.one didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: when i follow you,it doesn't work! The way of solving the problem is that i create the viewController instance outside the viewController which i add sub viewController in.pass the viewControllers as properties